# how to display video thumbnails using Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, thumbnails, universal-image-loader

I need to display video thumbnails using Universal Image Loader , any help pleaz,
i can get the thumbnail bitmap from this

```
Bitmap b= ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(
             "",MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

but how display it in imageloader because if  i display the bitmap the adapter will make the mobile slow,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two way :

**A: Use simple method to set adapter**

1. Please set bitmap in image using method setImageBitmap().
2. If you want set bitmap in universal image downloader.
3. Create a method in universal class

   ```
   public void setImageThumbnail(String videoPath, ImageView imgView) {

      Bitmap b=ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoPath,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
      imgView.setImageBitmap(b);

   }
   ```
4. use this method where you want.

**B :You can also use Lru-cache for adapter.**

1. Use worker thread to load bitmap.
2. Create lru cache hashmap to store bitmap.
3. For example please use below code:

http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/07/31/loading-caching-and-displaying-images-in-android-part-1/

for more detail you can use below link: 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

It will help for you.

Comment: not i didn't need "setImageBitmap" because i work in adapter so the work with bitmap make mobile very slow , i need load the thumbnail using uri in imageloader

Comment: check my answer agian.

Comment: yes pleaz  , can u explain more ur answer in section "B" , how i give the AsyncTask the bitmap an load it in my imageview

Comment: @mostafa Hashim please check example link. it will explain ur doubt.

Answer (score 0):

UIL accepts the `content://` `Uri` of the video and knows how to create a thumbnail.

For example, here is a `ListFragment` that displays a list of videos, using UIL-supplied thumbnails:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2013 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain   a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    http://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.video.list;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;

public class VideosFragment extends
    ContractListFragment<VideosFragment.Contract> implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>,
    SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder {
  private ImageLoader imageLoader;

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity host) {
    super.onAttach(host);

    ImageLoaderConfiguration ilConfig=
        new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getActivity()).build();

    imageLoader=ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(ilConfig);
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle state) {
    super.onActivityCreated(state);

    String[] from=
        { MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Video.Media._ID };
    int[] to= { android.R.id.text1, R.id.thumbnail };
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter=
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row, null,
                                from, to, 0);

    adapter.setViewBinder(this);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    CursorAdapter adapter=(CursorAdapter)getListAdapter();
    Cursor c=(Cursor)adapter.getItem(position);
    int uriColumn=c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
    int mimeTypeColumn=
        c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE);

    getContract().onVideoSelected(c.getString(uriColumn),
                                  c.getString(mimeTypeColumn));
  }

  @Override
  public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    return(new CursorLoader(
                            getActivity(),
                            MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            null, null, null,
                            MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE));
  }

  @Override
  public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor c) {
    ((CursorAdapter)getListAdapter()).swapCursor(c);
  }

  @Override
  public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    ((CursorAdapter)getListAdapter()).swapCursor(null);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean setViewValue(View v, Cursor c, int column) {
    if (column == c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID)) {
      Uri video=
          ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
              c.getInt(column));
      DisplayImageOptions opts=new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
          .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_media_video_poster)
          .build();

      imageLoader.displayImage(video.toString(), (ImageView)v, opts);

      return(true);
    }

    return(false);
  }

  interface Contract {
    void onVideoSelected(String uri, String mimeType);
  }
}
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Media/VideoList))

In `setViewValue()`, I get the video ID, assemble the associated video `content://` `Uri` via `ContentUris.withAppendedId()`, and use that with UIL.